# How to expand environment variables using keyboard shortcut in Fish?

Tags: fish, tab-completion

In Bash, the shortcut `Esc Ctrl-e` can be used to expand an environment variable at the shell:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/joe

$ $PATH<Press Esc Ctrl-e>
$ /home/joe
```

Is there a shortcut to achieve something similar in Fish?

Comment: [`M-C-e` is `shell-expand-line`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-display_002dshell_002dversion-_0028C_002dx-C_002dv_0029) in the bash readline implementation. I don't see a similar function [implemented in fish](https://fishshell.com/docs/2.7/commands.html#bind)

Comment: @glennjackman Can a user write such a function, bind it to a shortcut and add it to config.fish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
function bind_expand_all
    # what are the tokens of the current command line
    set tokens (commandline --tokenize)
    # erase the current command line (replace with empty string)
    commandline -r ""
    for token in $tokens
        # append the expanded value of each token followed by a space
        commandline -a (eval echo $token)" "
    end
    # move the cursor to the end of the new command line
    commandline -C (string length (commandline))
end
```

then

```
bind \e\ce bind_expand_all
```

And if this is your current command line (with the cursor at the underscore):

```
$ echo $HOME (date -u)_
```

when you hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>, you get

```
$ echo /home/jackman Thu May 10 19:27:18 UTC 2018 _
```

To store that binding permanently, add it to your `fish_user_key_bindings` function (create it if it does not exist):

> Key bindings are not saved between sessions by default. **Bare `bind` statements in config.fish won't have any effect because it is sourced before the default keybindings are setup.** To save custom keybindings, put the `bind` statements into a function called `fish_user_key_bindings`, which will be autoloaded.

- https://fishshell.com/docs/2.7/commands.html#bind

---

A little nicer:

```
function bind_expand_all
    set -l expanded
    for token in (commandline --tokenize)
        set expanded $expanded (eval echo $token)
    end
    set -l new (string join " " $expanded)
    commandline -r $new
    commandline -C (string length $new)
end
```

Comment: Nothing too fancy: create a list of the expanded tokens, replace the current commandline with the list joined with spaces.